# Создание составного элемента управления Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Нужен элемент управления состоящий из TextBox,Label,MaskedTextBox, которые находятся на Panel.Создаю класс, который содержит в качестве полей эти элементы управления и наследую его от UserControl. При динамическом создании данного элемента управления и добавлении его в коллекцию Controls главной формы, элемент не отображается на форме. Не знаю в чем проблема. Если кто-то решал подобную задачу,или сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите. Буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все правильно. Должно работать :).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что поскольку Panel на которой находятся элементы управления является дочернем элементом текущего элемента управления(который представлен моим классом) то координаты верхнего левого угла Panel надо указывать относительно левого верхнего угла родителя. По ошибке я указывал координаты превышающие размеры родителя, и элементы управления,которые я ожидал увидеть, соответственно отображались за пределами клиентской области родителя, поэтому были не видны. Огромное спасибо всем ,кто пытался помочь. Ценю вашу отзывчивость.